# PHP function to build string from numerals?

Tags: php

Hi is there a PHP function to build a string of alpha characters from numerals?

e.g

```
1 = a
2 = b
3 = c
```

etc?

Comment: each character has an unique ascii code: 
Take a look at this: http://www.asciitable.com/
I think you need code to convert ascii code to character am i right?

Comment: there is no way to detect if you have 26, it is `BF` or `Z`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [chr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) function combined with an offset for this e.g.:

```
$offset = 96;
echo chr(1 + $offset);
echo chr(2 + $offset);
echo chr(3 + $offset);
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want in the end, [`strtr` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) might be sufficient:

```
$str = strtr('1234567890', 'abcdefghij', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the string and use [ord()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) to convert from characters to numeric values. Then apply the necessary offset.
If you want to convert from numeral to characters, use [chr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php).

Comment: if I understand the question correctly, he wants to change numbers into letters, not the other way around